# How do I add a query param to Router.push in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

With NextJS, I'm trying to route to another page using an object that has a `to` and `as` field:

```
export const routes = {
  'BrowseList' : {
    'to' : '/apps/Browse/list',
    'as' : '/browse/list'
  }
  // ....
}
```

and then that's imported and used like so:

```
import { routes } from './__routes';
import Router from 'next/router';

// .... 

const { to, as } = routes.BrowseList;

Router.push(to, as);
```

which all works. My dilemma is that I'm trying to do something similar to this while attaching a query param. I'm trying to follow this example according to the [docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#with-url-object-1):

```
Router.push({
  pathname: '/about',
  query: { name: 'Zeit' },
})
```

What I've tried (which doesn't work):

```
Router.push({
  pathname : to,
  as,
  query    : { user_id: this.props.data.member.user.id },
});
```

which gives me a console warning of

```
Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format: as
```

I know I can maybe possibly just use string interpolation and do something like this:

```
Router.push(to, `${as}?user_id=`${this.props.data.member.user.id}`)
```

but I was wondering if there was something I'm missing in the doc's example that also adds the query param into my `as` value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You were close @nyphur. The `as` value goes as the second parameter of *push* and not inside the object that corresponds to `to` (check *router.d.ts* to see how *push* is defined). That's why you're getting the error `Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format: as`. After 10 months from your question maybe this could still be useful to someone looking for an answer. Assuming you have a way to build the query string for the `as` parameter, following @Gezim answer or by any other approach:

```js
Router.push({ pathname: to, query: { user_id: this.props.data.member.user.id } }, as, options);
```

**NOTE:** Based on @Gezim answer, if you format the string or `pathname` in the first parameter to contain your query params, it'll work BUT encoded values, if any, like `%2B` for instance will be decoded so you will get `+`. This doesn't happen if the query params object go inside `query`. Consider this if you have any kind of logic that depends on this.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the router in next.js doesn't have any convenient API to navigate to using a query string.

I created a utility class called `LinkCreator` with a `toQuery` method as follows. It uses `query-string` to create the query string:

```
import * as qs from 'query-string';
export class LinkCreator {
    static query(object) {
        return qs.stringify(object);
    }
    static toQuery(object, path = "/") {
        const query = this.query(object);
        return path + '?' + query;
    }
}
```

Then, it can be used with `Router.push` like so:

```
Router.push(LinkCreator.toQuery({ name: 'Zeit' }), '/about');
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit: at first I thought merging an object via spreading would be an easy fix, but then as a comment pointed out there needed to be some changes, so I have updated my answer to still utilize spreading, but unfortunately it does now make the `Routes` more complicated and involved, but the consumption of it is still straight forward.

I would also freeze the `Routes` object for peace of mind as well.

```js
import Router from 'next/router';

export const Routes = Object.freeze({
  BrowseList(query) {
    return [
      {
        pathname: '/apps/Browse/list',
        query
      },
      '/browse/list'
    ]
  }
  // ....
})

Router.push(
  ...Routes.BrowseList({
    paramName: "Param value here"
  })
)
```

### Additional Abstraction

```js
import Router from 'next/router';

const QueryRoutePath = (to, as, query) => ([
  {
    pathname: to,
    query
  },
  as
])

export const Routes = Object.freeze({
  BrowseList(query) {
    return QueryRoutePath(
      '/apps/Browse/list',
      '/browse/list',
      query)
  }
  // ....
})

const query = {
  paramName: "Param value here"
}

Router.push(
  ...Routes.BrowseList(query)
)
```